# Usage of Zorn's Lemma to prove that the intersection of all prime ideals contains only nilpotent elements.

Tags: commutative-algebra, axiom-of-choice, maximal-and-prime-ideals, nilpotence

I have read a couple proofs that [that the intersection of all prime ideals contains only nilpotent elements](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Nilradical) that use a claim like this:

> Suppose that $a$ is an element of $A$ that is not nilpotent. Let $S$ be the set of ideals of $A$ that do not contain any element of the form $a^n$. Since $(0) \in S$, $S$ is not empty; then by Zorn's Lemma, $S$ has a maximal element $\mathfrak{m}$.

However, it's not clear to me that every chain of ideals in $S$ has an upper bound, which appears necessary to use Zorn's Lemma. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union of elements of  such a chain is an ideal and an upper bound.